# Setup Java application to use live or test systems

Tags: java, environment, production

I have an application which I create a JAR for and subsequently upload to a unix server to run. It integrates with an external API and an internal database. Both of which we can consider to be 'live'.

I also have a duplicate instances of the server, the API and the database which will function as my test platform.

My application has all values in a config file which is referenced throughout. What structures can I use which will allow me to specify in one place in code whether the JAR I'm building should refer to the live environment credentials and values or the test environment credentials and values?

Comment: I generally avoid a jar built for an environment.  One of the implications is that the artifact you test is not the artifact that goes to production.  Spring Boot does a pretty good job of externalizing this, I'd recommend take a look at how they do it and maybe using that.  See, for e.g. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment.html#deployment-script-customization-conf-file

Comment: np, hope it helps.  :)